# Javascript array valueOf method

Tags: javascript

`[].valueOf()` method retuns array itself.According to this

```
document.write([["a"]],["b"])
```

should return ['a']b isn't it?But this is not happening ,it just writes `ab`.I just wanted to know the reason behind this.

For string elements .toString() method returns this,

```
["a","b"].toString()//a,b
```

But for elements with array it should return

```
[["a"],"b"].toString()//[a],b
```

Comment: I think it uses `toString()` not `valueOf()`

Comment: your edit's sample returns `a,b`, and no, the latter returns `a,b` because the `[].toString()` casts all its items to string before concatenating - nested arrays will be stringified recursively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass an object to document.write, Javascript converts the object to a string with .toString(). In this case, [Array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) will flatten and join the array with commas, and return it as a string.

```
["this", "is", "an", "array!"].toString(); // "this,is,an,array!"
[["a",["b"]], ["c"]].toString() // "a,b,c"
```

We can expand `document.write([["a",["b"]], ["c"]])` into the following:

```
var input = [["a",["b"]], ["c"], "d"];
Array.prototype.verboseToString = function verboseToString() {
  // Make a copy of the array, so we don't destroy the original
  var copy = this.slice(), i;
  for (i = 0; i < copy.length; i++) {
    // If this is an Array, call verboseToString() on it, and go deeper
    if (copy[i] instanceof Array === true) {
      copy[i] = copy[i].verboseToString();
    }
  }
  // copy contains non-arrays and we're ignoring other types' toString() output
  return copy.join(',');
}
document.write(input.verboseToString()); // "a,b,c,d"
```

Comment: but it only joins the elements of an array .But what when the element is an array itself.I just wanted the reason how js all do that.toString() method joins the elements of an array when they are string and this should happen the same when the elements are array .But that is not happening

Comment: It flattens the array before joining it. `[["a", ["b"]], ["c"]]` turns into `["a", "b", "c"]`, which is joined as `"a,b,c"`

Comment: thank u ,that was what i was searching for .Can u explain me how js flattens the original array

Comment: Technically, it's just going through recursively and converting each array to a string. So `[["a", ["b"]], ["c"]]` first gets converted to `[["a", "b"], "c"]` and then to `["a,b", "c"]` and then to "a,b,c"

Comment: It actually, never flattens to `["a", "b", "c"]`. It flattens to `["a,b", "c"]`

Comment: I'll see if I can't write up a more accurate elaboration. I didn't realize it went in that order, but it does make sense.

Comment: @jcsanyi How does that new function look to you? Adding in a `console.log(copy.join(','))` before the return results in `b`, `a,b`, `c`, `a,b,c,d`, which seems accurate.

Comment: @SpenserJ Looks good. I believe that's an accurate representation of what's happening internally.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write([["a"]]",",["b"])
```

write get unlimited arguments separated by commas so it is actually expected behavior

In order to print what you want use:

```
document.write(["a","b"])
```

This way you will print an array and not a list of arrays

Comment: @raam86 what will be the use of calling valueOf() method whatever it returns ,the toString() method will be called again

Comment: That still won't print an array. It will print the result of ["a","b"].join(","), as noted in [Array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString)

Comment: @SpenserJ thank you I was pointing out it will print the comma this way

Answer (score 1):

From **[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)**

> The text you write is parsed into the document's structure model.

So you send out an array it will just evaluate the array values to string to create a document structure which `[["a"]],["b"]` has none but just the text values.

If you do this:

```
document.write(["<a>a</a>", "<a>b</a>"])
```

You can see it creates 2 anchor elements separated by `,` so its just `array.join(',')`

or just provide this:

```
document.write(["<a>a</a>"], ["<a>b</a>"])
```

This time it will create 2 anchors you don't see a comma anymore.

Comment: the question is not about the need of coma,i need to know when ["a","b"].toString() is called it returns `ab` but it should return the same when [["a"],"b"].toString() it called i.e `["a"]b `

Comment: @Maizere i am not talking about a comma here. I am just telling you what it does...